# Can't find stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

When I try to update my table's data, I'm getting error

> Can't find stored procedure

What's wrong?

**SQL:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetContactName
   @Name char(20),
   @SecondName char(20) output
as
   SELECT @SecondName = [Second Name] 
   FROM WPF.dbo.contacts 
   WHERE Name = @Name
```

**C#:**

```
sqlConnection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetContactName", sqlConnection);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@Name";
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@SecondName";
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Char;
param.Size = 20;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection.Close();
```

**Edit1**

I'm using VS13 and SQL Server 2008 Management Studio.

I can't find stored procedure, but when I'm executing the SQL code, it says that the procedure already exists.

Connection string:

```
Data Source=HOME;Initial Catalog=WPF;Integrated Security=True
```

- Database : `WPF`
- Schema: `dbo.contacts`

Comment: Are you able to view your database in Sql Explorer and see that your Sproc exists? Does your application have permissions to see the stored procedure? Is your application pointing to the correct database / right credentials?

Comment: Can you show us your **connection string**? Also: in which database and schema did you create your stored procedure?

Comment: Can you confirm YOUR credentials have access to the stored procedure? You could attempt to delete it and re-add it to test.

Comment: Have you tried creating the sproc through code or through the query editor in MSSQL?

Comment: You have mentioned two errors in your explanation (can't find it, or it already exists) please clarify.

Comment: @Prescott I can delete (using **drop procedure**) it and re-add in the SQL Manager. I've created sproc throught the query editor in MSSQL.

Comment: @ElectricLlama **can't find**, when I press the button in my app. And **already exist** I'm getting when execute the SQL code in the second time

Comment: Yes. 'already exist' occurs because you are using CREATE PROCEDURE (not ALTER PROCEDURE). Don't worry about that for now. You need to open up the object browser in SSMS and see what schema that SP is in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, when you create a procedure using **sql-query**, it is not shown in the folder "Stored Procedures". But if you create a procedure by selecting the appropriate option from the **context menu** in the "Stored Procedures" folder, it is displayed and everything works.

Comment: That's not how it works. The problem must be something else. Maybe the proc was created in a different database.

Comment: No, I have only one non-system database - WPF.

Comment: There is no such thing as a folder for procedures. This folder just lists all procedures that were defined. If your proc does not show up there it does not exist. For whatever reason. Maybe it went into master? Why did you qualify the table name with the database name (WPF.dbo.contacts)? It didn't work without it, right? Because it went into the wrong database.

Comment: I have four system databases: master, model, msdb, tempdb. There is no stored procedure there. But yes, it didn't work without DB name. I dont know.. It is working and I'm glad =)

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem of database schema. Check to see if the default schema for the user id used in your connection string matches your SP's schema.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the USE YourdataBaseName follow by GO above your query.

```
**USE  YourdataBaseName
Go**

CREATE PROCEDURE GetContactName
   @Name char(20),
   @SecondName char(20) output
as
   SELECT @SecondName = [Second Name] 
   FROM WPF.dbo.contacts 
   WHERE Name = @Name
C#:
```